# Inline-initialized final member variable is somehow null

Tags: java, android, member, final

I have the following code in my Conversation class:

```
private ConversationListener conversationListener = null;
private final Integer conversationListenerLock = 0;

public ConversationListener getConversationListener() {
    synchronized (conversationListenerLock) {
        return conversationListener;
    }
}
```

I am now sometimes getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)
    at com.mobileoct.shared.data.Conversation.getConversationListener(Conversation.java:283)
    at com.mobileoct.android.colposcope.main.ConversationManager.loadConversationsForUser(ConversationManager.java:260)
    at com.mobileoct.android.colposcope.main.ConversationManager$1.run(ConversationManager.java:305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                    
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                    
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

It appears that, *somehow*, `conversationListenerLock` is `null`. How could that possibly be? How could I get into this public, *non-static* method of the Conversation class without having initialized the `conversationListenerLock` value? 
And how can I fix it so that that doesn't happen?

(As is clear from the stacktrace, this is running on Android, and thus appears to be some indeterminate version of Java that closely approximates Java 7.something.)

---

**EDIT**: To respond to some of the questions in the comments:

I am running this on a Samsung Galaxy J5 (SM-J500H), running Android 6.0.1. (I haven't yet run it on other devices, but this is the primary target device, so that doesn't matter much).

The only constructor for this class is:

```
public Conversation(String sessionId, String name, String ownerId, String userId) {
    dataType = DATA_TYPE;
    this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    this.setSessionId(sessionId);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setOwnerId(ownerId);
    this.setUserId(userId);
}
```

*However*, this class is sometimes instantiated by Gson, as in:

```
Conversation conversation = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, Conversation.class);
```

(There's more stuff in there between the `new GsonBuilder()` and the `.create()`, but I'm pretty certain it's not relevant.)

I don't know enough about unsafe publication to know whether that might fit the bill, but it seems like a likely culprit.

---

**EDIT #2** - here's "all code directly and indirectly invoked from the ctor, and the initializers of all other fields" (some copied from the parent class):

```
public static final String DATA_TYPE = "conversation";
private static final Class<?> s_postServlet = AddConversation.class;

protected String id;
private String sessionId;
private String name;
private String ownerId; // the user that created the conversation
private Boolean deleted = false;
private Date lastUpdated = new Date();
private User user;
private User owner;
private Session session;
private SortedSet<Collaborator> collaborators = new TreeSet<>();
private SortedSet<Message> messages = new TreeSet<>();
private Set<Notification> notifications = new HashSet<>();
private ConversationListener conversationListener = null;
private final Object conversationListenerLock = new Object();

// From parent class
protected String dataType;
protected Date timestamp = new Date();
protected String userId;


public Conversation(String sessionId, String name, String ownerId, String userId) {
    dataType = DATA_TYPE;
    this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    this.setSessionId(sessionId);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setOwnerId(ownerId);
    this.setUserId(userId);
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setOwnerId(String ownerId) {
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
}

// From parent class
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Comment: Please show (all) constructors of the `Conversation` class. You'd have to be doing something pretty exotic to make this fail... but here we are...

Comment: Does this affect a particular brand, model, or Android version?

Comment: I smell unsafe publication. You really need to show your constructors.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I'll wager lunch on my answer being correct on this one. The constructors are not relevant.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're on.

Comment: See further information added above

Comment: @rweiser please also show all code directly and indirectly invoked from the ctor, and the initializers of all other fields. Unsafe publication is easy to do by mistake, and it isn't always obvious.

Comment: Without answering *why* that field is null, since that's buried in the weeds somewhere, a trivial fix would be to make the field `static`: since you're synchronizing on the same instance (the cached zero), it doesn't make a difference if it's an instance or static variable; and static fields are guaranteed to be initialized once the class is loaded. Of course, you *can* have cycles in the class initialization which cause final fields to be read as uninitialized, but if you do, your class *really* is a mess.

Comment: @AndyTurner - but if I make it `static`, then that would essentially synchronize that method across _all_ instances of `Conversation`, no? (I understand that may be happening now anyway, due to @Bathsheba's point about cached Integers, but I'd rather fix that problem than rely on it as a "starting point" for a solution.)

Comment: @rweiser you do that anyway, since you're synchronizing on the boxed value of `0`, which is guaranteed to be cached. "From parent class" please show the same initializers + code called from the constructor of the parent class (and its parent classes - there's an implicit call to `super()` from this constructor).

Comment: The initializers from the parent class were already included (`dataType`, `timestamp` and `userId`). Parent class constructor is simply `public Data() {}`. And see my point above, about wanting to fix the mistake of the cached boxed `0`, rather than relying on it as a starting point for a solution. (I added that point as an edit to my comment, possibly after you first loaded/read it.)

Comment: You can't fix the mistake of the cached 0 in isolation: as you found by changing it to `Object`, it's got nothing to do with the value you're assigning it: it is that you are using the value before it is assigned. So, you've got to fix that problem first; the cached 0 is mere detail. You could replace it with `synchronized (this)`, and it would work (probably); but you've clearly got something lurking that needs sorting as well.

Comment: @rweiser So it happens also when you replace `Integer` with `Object`? In that case I think it has nothing to do with the nature of the `Integer` class itself. Then I suggest you edit your post replacing `Integer` with `Object`. Otherwise it'll lead to confusion by readers.

Comment: Replacing `Integer` with `Object` doesn't fix it, though I did it anyway for the purpose of correctness.
To prevent the null object, I made that `Object` `static` (which, I recognize, undoes any efficiency I might have gained by using an `Object` instead of an `Integer`, but it's the only solution that seemed to work).

Answer (score 2):

**You should never synchronize on an Integer in Java.**

Since you've set an `Integer` to 0, `conversationListenerLock` *must* refer to one of the cached `Integer`s, as it's in the range -128 to +127. Attempting to acquire its monitor is a particularly bad idea. The object does not belong to you, only the *reference*.

(I would suggest that your Java platform is displaying the diagnostic in error in an attempt to deal with the issue that you've presented it with, which, I think, amounts to a bug in your JVM.)

So as a rule of thumb, **don't** try to `synchronize` on an `Integer` in Java: A JVM reserves the right to cache *any* `Integer` value; not just the minimum range I've already stated.

The simplest workaround would be to write

```
private final Object conversationListenerLock = new java.lang.Object();
```

Comment: It's a bad idea, but this doesn't answer why it's null.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I've attempted to explain it with a bit of dusting up.

Comment: You've explained why you shouldn't synchronize on an Integer, not how it is possible for this reference to be null. The type isn't (apparently) relevant to the issue, because it's a really broken JVM if that cached value is null.

Comment: I'm confident I'm on the right lines here. In C and C++ we'd just say "it's undefined behaviour" and be done with it. I really can't say much more without looking at the particular JVM in considerable detail.

Comment: I think it's much more likely that OP is unsafely publishing the object from the constructor than it's a JVM bug/undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Are you writing under the assumption that synchronising on an `Integer` is fine?

Comment: "synchronising on an Integer is fine": Yes, because there's nothing special about `Integer` which means you can't: it's an object like any other. You *shouldn't*, because it's an object that any other object can get hold of, but that leads to starvation-type bugs, *not* nullness of a reference. I am strongly under the assumption, however, that [final fields are guaranteed to be assigned once the constructor completes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

Comment: Sorry, @Bathsheba - even after changing it to an `Object`, I still get the same exception (though your point is still helpful, in general!)

Comment: @rweiser and to be clear - are you changing the field *type* or the field *value* to Object?

Comment: Both. `private final Object conversationListenerLock = new Object();`

Comment: I'm a proud cat: you still must never synchronise on `Integer` types in Java. I'm not sure we can delve much deeper without a compilable example.

Comment: @Bathsheba note that your link isn't relevant here. The problem that exposes is *not* that synchronizing on `Integer` is inherently problematic, it is that [synchronizing on a non-final reference](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/SynchronizeOnNonFinalField) is; but the re-assignment can be hidden by the implicit auto-(un)boxing of the `++` operator for numeric types. You can create exactly the same problem with non-`Integer` types, but the assignment is more explicit.